# Why is jinja not passing content into bootstrap tabs beyond initial active tab?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

Content within first active tab renders perfectly. However, subsequent tabs fail to  display jinja generated content in their panes. These panes display HTML, and will display content explicitly provided via Flask, but they are not generating content between jinja {% for x in xs %} blocks. Here is my code... What have I overlooked?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <title>r.io</title>



  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>

</head>
{% block body %}
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('cs.index')}}">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/Logo_Header.png') }}" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="r.io"> r.io
      </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle mr-md-2" href="{{ url_for('cs.index') }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/active.png') }}" alt="D">
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('cs.C', r_id=r_id) }}">
              <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/inactive.png') }}" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="C"> C
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=logo)}}" alt="BTC" height="35px" width="35px"> &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <h1>Bn</h1>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Tech</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Fun</a>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">

        SOME STATIC TABLE CONTENT HERE

      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
**THIS FIRST TAB WORKS GREAT
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tab" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            <span>CHART GOES HERE</span>
            <table>
              <tr>
                {% for date in dates %}
                <td style="width: 120px; font-size: small; text-align: center;">{{ date }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>**

*########## THIS TAB DOES NOT RENDER Jinja Content. WHY? ################
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tab" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
            <div class="active" style="margin-left: 20px"><br>
              <h4>A Headline</h4>
              <table>
                {% for doc in docs %}
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=icon) }}"></td>
                  <td><a href="{{ doc.link }}">{{ doc.title }}</a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </table>*
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/popper-1.14.3.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Comment: What are you passing to the template in the way of docs? How are you passing it to the template? Is there a chance that list may be empty?

Comment: Hi @trevdev so the problem was actually in a typo someplace within my database models. I thought I had thoroughly debugged, but rebuilding the data models solved the issue. I should delete this question, but I appreciate your inquery and response. Thank you.